# Why with glmnet I obtain different coefficients for the different categories I want to classify?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, glmnet

I am performing a multinomial logistic regression using glmnet. I have 7 classes of trees to predict and different predictors. What I do not understand is why when I plot the coefficents vs. log lambda in the graph it appears coefficients: Spruce fir response (where Spruce fir is one of the trees). When you ask for coefficients it gives back 7 different set of coefficients once for every class. What does it means? 
I hope the question is clear, I have tried to post directly an image, but apparently it posts the link. Here it is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GAyN.png

Comment: You are confused as to why you are getting 7 different coefficients, one for each level of your dependent categorical variable?

Comment: Could you post a copy of the R code + give more info about your predictors.